# ngModel and ngFor select options

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-modules

Im doing a form that changes with selected option.

```
<select multiple class="form-control col-6" id="efeitos" [(ngModel)]="test" name='effect'>
                <option *ngFor='let eff of effects' [ngValue]="eff">{{eff.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <textarea class="col-5" readonly>{{test.desc}}</textarea>
```

textarea never appears.

```
<p>{{test | json}}</p>
```

Shows: [ { "name": "effect", "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor" } ] instead of desired { "name": "effect", "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor" }

first post here, pls some help

Answer (score 0):

You get the array in `test` because you use the `multiple` attribute, just remove `multiple` (if you need the `multiple`, then Array, I think, is the expected result for you)

Answer (score 0):

it could be also this way: {{

{{test[0] | json}}

}}

Answer (score 0):

When the property `multiple` is supplied to the `select` tag, there could be multiple selections. So naturally the `test` variable would be an array. You could try to gather `desc` properties from all the selected elements using array `map` function.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  test: Effect[] = [{ 'name': '', 'desc': 'please select an effect'}];

  getDesc() {
    return this.test.map(item => item.desc)
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<textarea class="col-5" readonly>
{{ getDesc() }}
</textarea>
```

Note: This method is inefficient. If you aren't controlling the change detection strategy manually, `getDesc()` function might be called multiple times than intended. This will be a bottleneck when the `test` array has too many elements since the entire array is iterated for each call.